# Dynamically get data from firebase realtime database during runtime in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem: I want to get data from a specific node from firebase during runtime. It should display "stats" of a player that was selected before. Now I could use on() to get all the data in the beginning, but I want to save data transfers by only downloading the data of on player if I need to, so I tried to use once like this:

```
    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

    function getScoresOfPlayer(player) {
      console.log(player);
      var selectedPlayerScores = [];

      firebaseRef.once('value').then(function(snap) {
        snap.child('scores').child('thierschi').forEach(function(child) {
          selectedPlayerScores.push([child.key, child.val()]);
        });
      });

      return selectedPlayerScores;
    }
```

The problem is that it retruns the array before the data was loaded into it. Also I checked the docs and didn't find a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `getScoresOfPlayer` function returns `selectedPlayerScores` before the promise returned by the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method resolves.

You should include the `return` within the `then()`, as follows:

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

function getScoresOfPlayer(player) {
  console.log(player);
  var selectedPlayerScores = [];

  return firebaseRef.once('value')  //return here as well
  .then(function(snap) {
    snap.child('scores').child(player).forEach(function(child) {  //I guess it should be child(player) and not child('thierschi') here
      selectedPlayerScores.push([child.key, child.val()]);
    });

    return selectedPlayerScores;
  });

}
```

which means that you have to call your function as follows, since it is going to be asynchronous and to return a promise:

```
getScoresOfPlayer('xyz')
.then(function(selectedPlayerScores) {
   ....
})
```